# Impersonation between 2 servers

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to move a document from one SharePoint farm to another but I believe this may be an asp.net issue.

I am using the client object model for the target server and I keep getting issues with access denied when I don't manually set credentials.

When I create new NetworkCredentials and give the client context those it works.

The user I am trying to impersonate does have permission to add the item (I am using the same user in the NetworkCrendentials that I make)

Is there something that needs to be done to allow impersonation between multiple server?

Comment: It looks like you have a double-hop issue.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx

Comment: This does look like the issue I am having.  So I guess that means I either use a set of credentials for everyone or I set up the delegation stuff.